# Image not displaying in Xamarin forms using XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display an Image in my Xamarin forms project using `XAML` but is is not displaying.
This is the code:

```
<Image x:Name="myimage" Source="logo.jpg"/>
```

I have set myimage's build action to `embedded resource`. I also tried this

```
<Image x:Name="myimage" Source="MyXamarinProject.logo.jpg"/>
```

Where `MyXamarinProject` is my namespace. But both not working. What is wrong here?

Comment: Is it in any folder? You also have to add that, for example: `MyXamarinProject.folder.logo.jpg`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis it is in the root of project.

Comment: @Dungeon you need to add it to the platform folders

Comment: @Dungeon Check these: _On Android_: right click on the image -> **Properties**.  In Properties window,  make sure that **Build Action** is set to **AndroidResource**. _On iOS_, **Build Action** should be set to **BundleResource**

Comment: I can attest to @Dungeon 's comment. Somehow (I assume by default) I put an image into the Resources > drawable folder [in my Android project] and its `Build Action` was set as *AndroidAsset* and was not displaying. I saw this post and changed it to *AndroidResource* and bewm, I got my image [displayed].

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to avoid decreasing application performance or problems displaying the images on different screen resolutions is adding each image on each platform specific folder:

- Android: Project -> Resources -> Drawable (or each resolution drawable folder (-hdpi,-xhdpi...))
- iOS: You can create an asset catalog for each image or use Project -> Resources folder.

And then, use the image name on XAML file. No code needed.

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspecting the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#using-xaml) for this, it is not as easy as just specifying the path.

First, Create an `IMarkupExtension`

```
[ContentProperty (nameof(Source))]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
 public string Source { get; set; }

 public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
 {
   if (Source == null)
   {
     return null;
   }

   // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
   var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

   return imageSource;
 }
}
```

Then consume it in your XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkingWithImages;assembly=WorkingWithImages"
   x:Class="WorkingWithImages.EmbeddedImagesXaml">
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
   <!-- use a custom Markup Extension -->
   <Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg}" />
 </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Note that you have to add a custom namespace to your page, in this case: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkingWithImages;assembly=WorkingWithImages"`

Answer (score 0):

So, I can not display an image using `XAML` only. I am pretty satisfied with both the answers. Although this is how I displayed the image without pasting into the android and iOS(to their respective folders) and without making `IMarkupExtension`.
I put one line of code into `C#` code behind and that worked:

```
myimage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MyXamarinProject.logo.jpg");
//logo.jpg must be Embedded Resource.
```

This could not be the right answer but it can be a choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Visual Studio Mac:
my XAML :

```
<Image x:Name="myimage" Source="logo.jpg"/>
```

my resources was :  logo.jpg

But the file was saved in the file system as Logo.jpg (Capital L).

I just modified it to logo.jpg and rebuild all.