# Image not showing on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add images to my project but they are not showing up. I have looked all on Google and can't find a solution. I have tried the build actions, putting them in folders, looked through the code. I can't see where I'm going wrong. Here are some images because I could not figure out how to post the code to where it would accept it. My issue is no matter how I try to add images to my project and code it, the image does not show up.

[image: xaml.cs]

[image: xaml]

[image: Solutions Explorer]

Comment: have you tried reading the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes, Jason. I have looked through documents and I can't see anything. I know it is something I'm doing wrong, I just can't see what. I'm following a video on Udemy and others were having the issue, but it turns out they were having an issue with the file path name, but I checked and mine was good.

Comment: first, place the images in the correct folders (not Assets/Images) with the correct build action for each platform.  If you do that, then you should just be able to refer to them by file name in XAML.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I will look to see about the documentation. For some reason the video I'm watching told me to do it this way so I just assumed it was right.

Comment: You can use your images as embedded resource, but additionally you have to specify path for each platform in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add images in xamarin.forms, you can take a look the following  steps.

For Android:

Placing images in the **Resources/drawable** folder, and left-click image and change image property **Build action** as **AndroidResource**.

The code in PCL:

```
   <Image Source="a11.jpg" />
```

[image]

For ios:

Double-click **Asset Catalog/Assets**, then clicking **Plus Button** to select **Add Image Set**, then right-click to rename this image name.

The code in PCL:

```
  <Image Source="a11.jpg" />
```

[image]

[image]

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64678242/592651
in my case it was case sensitive file names in the file system.